# i want to echo name from database where id is account number and account number is session id

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to echo name from database where id is account number and account number is session id.

my db type = MySQL Database

TABLE = `accounts`

```
Table columns = 
  `id` bigint(16) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Which database system are you using? What are your table names? What have you tried so far? I'm guessing this could be a simple SELECT with WHERE but I don't know anything about your database.

Comment: ok i have done that

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT name
FROM accounts
WHERE id = session_id;
```

A few questions:

1. Where does your account_number come from?
2. Where does your session_id come from?
3. Asking for "where ID is account number and account number is session ID" is the same as "where ID is session ID", so why do you need the account number?